# SSRS Subscription fails "Thread Being Aborted"

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I have a huge report which works fine when I browse through report viewer. I have created a subscription so I can run this in the background. The subscription works if it's the only subscription running. If I run 2 subscriptions starting at the same time and pointing to the same report, the thread is aborted for one subscription and the other one works.

I have tried all suggestions with the configuration keys in `rsreportserver.config`, but no luck.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with resources on the SSRS server. How much RAM do you have on the server, compared with your development PC?

Comment: I am working on DEV server, 4GB RAM windows 2003 server. If i run some other subscriptions at same time which are pointing to smaller reports they all run smoothly. so its the problem with this big report that too if i try to run more than one subscription attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was the resources issue. it's to do with the RAM. If it takes up to 90% then SSRS restarts, hence losing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was a timeout setting. In the report portal in the Report Properties management page the default settings is "Use the system default setting". I changed this to "Allow report to run for 3600 seconds before timing out", and then the report completed successfully. I believe the default setting is 1800 seconds(30 minutes) so changing to 3600 seconds (60 minutes) give the report enough time to complete.